# create date object by hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to setup a `setTimeout` function and need to calculate the seconds for the callback. Let's say I want to execute a function at *12:00 (HH-MM)* I have to calculate the timespan up to this time. If the time has already passed the next day  is relevant.

I get the current date time with `new Date()`

I know I can calculate the timespan in seconds by using

```
const difference = dateTimeOne.getTime() - dateTimeTwo.getTime();
const differenceInSeconds = difference / 1000;
```

Is there a way creating a second date object by passing in the hours and minutes or do I have to calculate it on my own?

An example would be `new Date('12:45')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var minutes = 42;

for (var hours = 1; hours < 24; hours+=3) {
  var newAlarm = setAlarm(hours, minutes);
  out(newAlarm)
}



function out(date) {
  var now = new Date()
  
  if (date.getDate() != now.getDate()) {
    console.log('tomorrow: ' + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes())
  } else {
    console.log('today: ' + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes())
  }
}
function setAlarm(hours, minutes) {
  var now = new Date();
  var dateTarget = new Date();
  
  dateTarget.setHours(hours)
  dateTarget.setMinutes(minutes)
  dateTarget.setSeconds(0)
  dateTarget.setMilliseconds(0)
  
  if (dateTarget < now) {
    dateTarget.setDate(dateTarget.getDate()+1)
  }
  return dateTarget
}
```

See this [Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype)

Comment: almost, if the time has already passed I have to set the day to next day. That's why I asked if I have to do it manually

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the date and then check whether it is in the past. If it is, just add another day.

```js
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(12);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);

if (d < new Date()) {
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(d);
```